# BufferedReader is not reading quotation mark character

Tags: java, string, special-characters, bufferedreader, quotes

I am trying to read the character: " from BufferedReader onto a string. However, it displays the quote character as a square box.

```
            //Opens file
            File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
            //filePath
            String filePath = file.getPath();

            //Holds a line of text from the file
            String line = null;

            try
            {
                //Reads text from file
                FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(filePath);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

                //Reads each line onto the left text area (encryptMessageTA)
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
            }
            //File not found
            catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
            {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage()); //prints exception
            } 
            //Input/Output exception
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage()); //prints exception
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not a problem with the `BufferedReader`. It may be a problem with the `FileReader` or with where `System.out` prints, because it's a code page problem.

When `FileReader` is reading the file, it's reading in the default code page, usually Windows-1252 if you're using Windows in the US.

The real problem is that your file contains non-ASCII quotation marks. Unicode has a lot of different quotation marks. [See here for list](http://unicode-table.com/en/sets/quotation-marks/). The most common ones are:

- `"` [QUOTATION MARK (U+0022)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0022/index.htm) - This is the normal ASCII character
- `“` [LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK (U+201C)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201c/index.htm)
- `”` [RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK (U+201D)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201d/index.htm)

If your file contains any of the last two, and your console cannot display those, you'll see boxes, which represent failed mappings of characters.